# Android Screenshot Plugin Working in Cordova 2.0

Tags: java, android, cordova, eclipse-plugin, cordova-2.0.0

I am currently developing an Android app using cordova 2.0. Obviously the plugins.xml has been depreciated and everything is now housed in config.xml. I was just wondering if anyone has managed to get the Phonegap Screenshot plugin working in Eclipse and Cordova 2.0 working on android.

Plugin can be found:

https://github.com/josemando/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Screenshot

I have added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to my Android manifest xml. And made sure that:

```
<plugin name="Screenshot" value="org.apache.cordova.Screenshot"/>
```

is added to my config.xml (that now contains all plugin information from plugin.xml)

Screenshot.js is added to the directory:

```
assets/www/js/
```

However I am unsure where exactly to place the Screenshot.java file. The example has it in:

```
 src / org / apache / cordova /
```

However as I did not have this directory I simply placed it in:

```
src/uk.co..appname1.appname2/
```

When I did this however it produced errors, the first one being:

```
The declared package "org.apache.cordova" does not match the expected package "uk.co.mysitename.appname1.appname2"  Screenshot.java /Project Name/src/uk/co/mysitename/appname1/appname2line 8  Java Problem
```

This refers to this line in the Screenshot.js:

```
package org.apache.cordova;
```

The two suggested actions to fix this are to:

1. Move 'Screenshot.java' to package 'org.apache.cordova' (this directory doesn't exsist atm)
2. Or change package directory to 'uk.co.mysitename.appname1.appname2'

The second error says:

```
The method run() of type new Runnable(){} must override a superclass method
```

The suggested action for this being to "remove '@override' annotation"

I have tried to do every possible combination of these however I cannot seem to make progress and get it all to link up. Usually because it thinks that CordovaRef isn't referenced. I am unsure if the plugin even works on Cordova 2.0.0. I have some experience with Phonegap/Cordova but only in ios with Xcode and Objective C plugins. I am new to Java, Eclipse and Android. Any help or clarification on any of these matters would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer resolved by:

[Phonegap Screenshot plugin in Cordova 2.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424865/phonegap-screenshot-plugin-in-cordova-2-0-0)

Answer/solution provided by Simon MacDonald