# Phonegap Screenshot plugin in Cordova 2.0.0

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I have set up the screenshot plugin from github, located here:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Screenshot

I set it up as instructed and with 1.8.1 of cordova. It worked and the screenshot was saved to the phone. However it fails with cordova 2.0.0.

Screenshot.java code:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/Android/Screenshot/src/org/apache/cordova/Screenshot.java

Screenshot.js code:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/Android/Screenshot/www/Screenshot.js

Due to the advice of a very clever man called Simon MacDonald, I removed line 31 and 38 from the JS file shown above.

However when I try to use the screenshot plugin with cordova 2.0.0 I receive these errors:

```
ERROR: org.json.JSONException: Value undefined of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray.
Error: Status=8 Message=JSON error
file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.0.0.js: Line 938 :  Error: Status=8 Message=JSON error
Error: Status=8 Message=JSON error at file:///android_asset_/www/cordova-2.0.0.js:938
```

line 938 of the cordova.js is:

```
 // If error, then display error
    else {
        console.log("Error: Status="+v.status+" Message="+v.message);
```

but im almost certain this is a compatibility error. Does anyone know a fix for this, or even a reason. Im abit lost. Any help is appreciated.

I call the screenshot.js with this code:

```
function takeScreenShot() {
cordovaRef.exec("Screenshot.saveScreenshot");
```

}

Any help massively appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just upgraded it to support v2.0.0:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/commit/88a57e1c232f604f73be5bd82868d711ac235424

Comment: Thank you, that's awesome of you. Utmost respect to you and people like you.

Comment: I have been running into the same issue as above on Line 938. I even went back to running 2.0.0 clean from the example app and inserting the screenshot plugin there but it still won't work. Same error as above. The only extra piece of info I get is such:

ERROR: org.json.JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String can not be converted to JSONArray

Comment: how to use this plugin for android